# Jqgrid: get count of rows post applying local filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to get the count of all records posts applying local filters. Currently, I am getting all rows instead of filters rows.

jqgrid version= 5.3.0 free version

I tried to using lastSelectedData and data methods. lastSelectedData is giving a null record. data is giving all records. but I need to get all filtered rows.

```
gridElem.jqgrid.('getGridParam', 'lastSelectedData') // return null
```

```
gridElem.jqgrid.('getGridParam', 'data') //returns all records
```

Comment: jqGrid 5.x does not have free version. You maybe use a trail version, which is different.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.

On loadComplete we are get the actual filtered count as **data.records** where data is parameter of loadComplete method.

I am storing that in private variable and using it.

```
loadComplete:(data) => {
   console.log(data.records)
}
```